# Has any one gotten @marko/testing-library to work with vitetest?

Tags: vite, fastify, vitest, marko

I have a project in Vite, Fastify and Marko and am trying to use Vitest.

I want to test individual components/templates. Say pass in inputs (props) and test if the output (typically HTML) is as expected.

The [Marko Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/marko-testing-library/intro) supplies this but currently, with Vitest, it does not recognize the inputs. It returns an error when trying to "render" the template, saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'session')
 ❯ _marko_template._.__vite_ssr_import_4__.default.t src/components/menu-main/menu-main.marko:13:16
     11|     </li>
     12|     <li>
     13|       <if(input.session.firebaseAuthenticated)>
       |                ^
     14|         ${ input.session.displayName} <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
     15|       </if>
 ❯ renderer node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/components/renderer.js:218:5
 ❯ proxyRenderer node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/vdom/hot-reload.js:73:21
 ❯ Proxy.renderTagHelper node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/helpers/render-tag.js:15:77
 ❯ _marko_template._.__vite_ssr_import_5__.default.t src/components/menu-main/menu-main.marko?marko-server-entry:8:3
 ❯ renderer node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/components/renderer.js:218:5
 ❯ proxyRenderer node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/vdom/hot-reload.js:73:21
 ❯ safeRender node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/renderable.js:7:5
 ❯ Template.render node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/renderable.js:139:14
 ❯ renderResult node_modules/@marko/testing-library/dist/cjs/index-browser.js:59:72
 ❯ Proxy.render node_modules/@marko/testing-library/dist/cjs/index-browser.js:59:30
 ❯ src/components/menu-main/menu-main.test.js:8:30
```

If, in the template, I check "all the way up the chain" (as I should) in my conditional this error goes away.

```
<if(input?.session?.isXYZ)>
    <a ...>Log Out</a>
</if>
<else>
    <a ...>Log In</a>
</else>
```

But of course I am very explicitly (trying) to pass in `input.session.isXYZ` as true.

In any case, then the error changes to:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
 ❯ morphChildren node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/vdom/morphdom/index.js:269:41
 ❯ morphdom node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/vdom/morphdom/index.js:684:3
 ❯ AsyncVDOMBuilder.B_ node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/vdom/AsyncVDOMBuilder.js:394:7
 ❯ RenderResult.getNode node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/RenderResult.js:61:20
 ❯ getEl node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/RenderResult.js:106:23
 ❯ RenderResult.appendTo node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/dom-insert.js:31:16
 ❯ Proxy.render node_modules/@marko/testing-library/dist/cjs/index-browser.js:61:33
 ❯ async /home/ee/code/dibbs/dibbs-marko/src/components/menu-main/menu-main.test.js:11:25
```

But there is no reference to `id` in that component.

Even if I make the component just `<div></div>`
I get this `id` error. I assume it must be looking beyond the component/template I imported into my test script and am trying to test on.

I can look at `node_modules/marko/dist/runtime/vdom/morphdom/index.js:269:41` etc of course but before I go down that rabbit hole, I wanted to ask here. Any ideas?

The testing Script:

```
import { render } from "@marko/testing-library";
import template from "./menu-main.marko";
import { test } from 'vitest'


test('login menu item shows correct state', async (ctx) => {

  const { container } = await render(template, {
      session: {
        firebaseAuthenticated: false,
      }
  });

  expect(container).stringContaining("Log In");

})
```